# Switches, light and receptacle

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

I want to install two switches by my front door one switch controlling a outside light at the corner of my house,  and the other switch controlling a receptacle right next to the light at the corner of my house..
I was thinking of running 12/2 from each switch,  run one to the light and run another to the receptacle.
IS THERE ANOTHER WAY..
??

Comment: TO . RMDman,,,  So basically instead if running 12/2 from each switch.  Your saying just run one 12/3 and that will take care if both,,  1 ] a switch for light and 2] a switch for receptacle... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a cable with hot, neutral and ground at the switch location, then use 12/3 cable.

One hot (black) for the outlet. (if outside must be a GFCI)

The other hot (Red) to the light

The neutral (white) and ground are shared.

Run the cable to the light box first then to the outlet box.  Let the black wire just relay through the light box and don't connect it to anything on the light.

On the switch side. The red on the switch to the light, black on the switch to the outlet.  Neutrals all tied together, Grounds tied and pigtailed to ground the switches.  Hot from the breaker, pigtailed to provide power to both switches.

Comment: Actually, all he needs is 12/3 from switch to light and then 12/2 on to the outlet. Might be able to save a tidbit of money.